# D3: can't set proper columns in .datum()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphics

I'm digging D3.js and found `datum()` function.

[That's my current testing page, based on some example.](http://pastebin.com/eRVv1J2S)

[Example data.](http://pastebin.com/mkULKbra)

`.datum()` use:

```
label.append("rect", "text")
      .datum(function() { return this.nextSibling.getBBox(); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x - (d.width*1.5)+labelPadding*2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + labelPadding; })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width * 3; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height-d.y; })
      .attr("class", "pink_grad");
```

The problem is that I can't place columns good — their height counts wrong. 
How to do this properly?

[image: something went wrong]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. Working code:

```
label.append("rect", "text")
      .datum(function() { return this.nextSibling.getBBox(); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x - (d.width*1.5)+labelPadding*2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + labelPadding; })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width * 3; })
      .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height-y(data[i].blue); })
      .attr("class", "pink_grad");
```

The only problem left is horizontal alignment, which is not part of this question.

[image: how fix this one?]